# Why different paint image in ListView and ImageListEditor?

Tags: delphi, listview, treeview, vcl, imagelist

I created simple image with two layers from red point and gray transparent and save to PNG. Then I created project and added **`TListView`** and  **`TImageList`** with options `ColorDepth=cd32Bit`, `DrawingStyle=dsTransparent`. Than added PNG image and set image index to ListView I saw different painted image. Maybe somebody know how did paint correctly? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If the issue is that the image looks to have a gray square as background in the TListView, while not in the ImageList, I can not reproduce your issue. In my test with XE7 VCL desktop application and a true transparent image, it looks the same (round without a square bg) in both the TListView and ImageList. With what editor did you make the image, and how?

Comment: Which version of Delphi, and why are themes disabled?

Comment: Cannot reproduce either (XE2). Drawing style is irrelevant, the listview assumes responsibility for drawing. Edit: tested now with runtime themes disabled as per @David's comment, can reproduce. That seems to be your answer.

Comment: If you have time look my test project and image, I'll be appreciate. I created in Photoshop CS2. I attached project and image.[link]https://yadi.sk/d/MN82feR_ddcYZ

Comment: It's XE7 version. Can you tell me where find themes to Enable? Or you mean Windows themes?

Comment: Yes, Windows themes.

Comment: I change to standart Windows theme and it's look the same https://yadi.sk/i/2L6aN_2WdddWe

Comment: Select the image in the ImageList Editor and look to the Selected Image square in top left of the dialog. I don't know why the bottom preview shows as if the background is completely transparent, but it isn't. Additionally, it shows the correct image the first time you add it through the editor.

Comment: But I open this image in another image viewer and this PNG image looks the same in the bottom preview ImageEditor not in top left of the dialog.[Screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/sQ_Fc9jMddzfe)

Comment: @Ride - Select Tools->Options->View->Background colour in XnView, set it to black. View your picture again.

Comment: I did, but nothing changed.[Screeshot](https://yadi.sk/i/GCn-Dejlde2iz)

Comment: Does that look like to you that the background is transparent?

Comment: Then I reopen image in XnView, it's look like this - [Screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/kpNUxBOSde3LF). This image not full transparent he transparent for 70%. Then I creating I had two layers. One full gray with 70% transparent. Second layer with paint red circle with edge of the circle transparent.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Image background is not fully transparent. Listview image background is not fully transparent. Top left preview of imagelist editor background is not fully transparent. Bottom preview of imagelist editor background is fully transparent (only after the 1st preview of the image). Guess who's wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. But I don't understand why in ListView look different then in image viewers?  I combine images [Screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/ti74adx0de5fe). In ListView more gray then  in image viewers. Then I first look I think image in the bottom preview show correct but it's third view.

Comment: Save your png as a 32bit (A8R8G8B8) bmp with an external editor (XnView is fine) and use that image in the imagelist. Now it looks like as if the background is completely transparent in the listview. Go figure!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found answer for my question. **TImageList** using **Comctl32.dll**("Algorithm hidden within a dll. But it is called “Black Source Method” (by Ron Jerry). Picture is changed before painting."), **TImage** and **other viewers** using **Msimg32.dll**("Looks like a most suitable function for drawing a pictures with partial transparency") and **some viewers** may using **GDI32.dll**. And this different paint not only PNG and also ICO. I attached [Project](https://yadi.sk/d/MN82feR_ddcYZ) and [Screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/lhCrCMdzde8LA). Thanks all who try help me!

Comment: This makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: I've not been able to open any of those `yadi.sk` links and do not know what it looks like now. What did you change in your project if it now works ok?

Comment: I didn't change project to fix. Only show how different paint the **same PNG and ICO** in **TImageList** and **TImage**. I can't qualified tell problem and how fix, but for with [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9142/Adding-and-using-bit-alphablended-images-and-ic) might read full information. I fixed **TImageList** control problem for self I started using [TPngImageList](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26127). I can reload project to another servise if you tell me some one.